# Show warning if plugin is missing

Tags: theme-development, updates, automatic-updates

Sorry if this question is a bit to trivial, but I'm writing a theme that depends on a plugin to be installed. It's a multilingual theme, so I absolutely need the user to have [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/) installed. I thought about just copying the plugin files into my theme, but that would mean my theme users won't get Polylang updates.

So I hope you agree the best solution is to force the user to install polylang. Now, I would like to know what is the best way to let the user know he needs to install polylang? Is it possible to install a plugin automatically? What should happen if the user uninstalls polylang afterwars, just break the theme, or fall back to twentyeleven theme?

I would really love to hear some other people's ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

sample code that you can addopt and chage... to check is plugin installed. 
// addition check on init hook.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_73859_init');
function wpse_73859_init(){
    // if - we in wp-admin
    // if - we class of polylang not found
    // and if we can manage_options (there a lot of different 
    //     capabilities you can use install_plugins for example...)

    if (!class_exists('Polylang') && current_user_can('manage_options')){
        // message function created on a fly... 
        $msg = create_function('', 'echo "<div class=\"updated\"><p>require polylang plugin</p></div>";');
        // and finaly notice! 
        add_action('admin_notices', $msg);
    }
}
```

You actually can install plugin ( do silent download / unziping / actiavation) but its SO unacepted that you can't imaging. You basicly breaking privacy of person who use your theme.

Comment: 1) I wanted to make a few edits in the Answer, but I don't get this: *"in SO unacepted that you can't imaging"*. Can you link to some reading about it? So this can be better explained. ..... 2) Calling `admin_init` avoids checking for `is_admin()`. ..... 3) `admin_notices` requires an `echo` not a `return` :o[)

Answer (score 1):

```
// The is_plugin_active() function is only included by default in the admin,
// load it on the front-end too if needed.
if ( ! function_exists('is_plugin_active'))
{
    include_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

// Check if a certain plugin is activated
if ( ! is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php'))
{
    // It's probably too drastic to simply exit, but do whatever you want here
    exit('Plugin X requires plugin Y. Please, install plugin Y.');
}
```

Codex: [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)